# Using fopen() in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, fopen, stdio

I am puzzled by a crash I keep getting due to an error at this section of code:

```
                FILE *fid200;
                fid200 = fopen ( "Length200Vector.txt" , "w" );
                if (fid200 == NULL)
                    perror("Error opening Length200Vector.txt");
                for (int n = 0; n<200; n++) {
                    if (n == 0) {
                        fprintf (fid200, "%f", self.avgFeatureVect[0][n]);
                    }
                    else {
                    fprintf (fid200, ", %f", self.avgFeatureVect[0][n]);
                    }
                }
                fprintf (fid200, "\n");
                fclose(fid200);
```

The error is: Error opening Length200Vector.txt: Operation not permitted.

The file is residing in my Resources folder for my project and this line is being executed in a .mm file. Within the same project in .cpp files I am using practically the same exact code which runs without a problem. Can't seem to figure this one out...

Thanks

Comment: Does the code run `chdir(2)` or `fchdir(2)` at some earlier point in execution? What's the output of `ls -l Length200Vector.txt ; ls -ld . ; id` ? Unrelated -- why the complicated `if (n == 0)` that apparently does nothing?

Comment: Put this before your `fopen` line: `NSLog(@"wd = %@", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath]);`  Does it print your Resources directory path?

Comment: Is this a Mac OS X app or an iOS app?

Comment: Remember that `perror()` just prints an error message; it doesn't terminate your program.  IF the `fopen()` call fails, you try to write to the file anyway (and all the `fprintf()` calls should fail as well).

Comment: sarnold - chdir(2) and fchdir(2) do not run. The n==0 is so the first entry is not preceded by a ",". rob mayoff - this is an iOS app and the NSLog statement prints: wd = /private/var/mobile/Applications/DF60ABC3-95A7-40DD-A3F2-D1FD493138E4/cashconverter.app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding your comment that this is an iOS App: you are not allowed (in terms of the iOS sandbox) to perform **modifying** ("w" in fopen()) file access to anything in iOS applications other than to files located in your applications "Documents" directory (or for general application resources the ~/Library/Application Support/"bundle ID" directory and for temporary files the directory that is returned by a call to the NSTemporaryDirectory() function[1]).

Get access to the "Documents" directory by something like this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs_dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you have a resource file already that you will need to modify during the execution of your app, you will have to copy it to the "Documents" directory first, then modify it.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW1

Comment: That's not quite right. There are directories other than the documents directory you can write to (for example, the caches/temp directories, other places in your library directory). The key is that you can't write to your app bundle, which is where your resources live.

Comment: You are right. I will look up the reference and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I fixed this by changing the settings in Targets -> Signing and Capabilities -> App Sandbox -> File Access Type -> User Selected File  permission and access.